# replace characters in a json file

Tags: python, json, formatting

I've done some wrong manipulation of a 100 json files. Not sure what happened, but most of my json files now have a random number of the last characters repeated (as per image below).
Is there a way to clean a json file by deleting characters starting from the last one, until the json file has returned into a clean json format ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The short answer is `no`. It looks like you've overwritten part of the file with a shorter version, leaving the original. You are supposed to parse the file with the `json` library, make changes to the resulting object and rewrite the file as text.

Comment: Please include your code and the output as text and not as images.

Comment: @ewokx there is no code and no output to show unfortunately. That's what I'm actually looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions. An alternative would be string manipulation, but in this case regex is quicker to write, especially for one-time-use code.

```
import re

files = ['a.json','b.json',...] # populate as needed

for filename in files:
    with open(filename,'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
    
    new_content = re.match('([\s\S]+\}\]\}\})[\s\S]+?',content).group(1)
    
    with open(filename,'w') as file:
        file.write(new_content)
```

This regex has several parts.
`[\s\S]` matches all characters (whereas `.` would not match newlines and some other characters).
The greedy `[\s\S]+` matches as much as possible, and the lazy `[\s\S]+?` matches as little as possible (in this case, the trailing text we don't want).

We then parenthesise the part we do want to keep, `([\s\S]+\}\]\}\})`, and extract that using `.group(1)` and write this to the file.

For more information, see [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean), and in future I would suggest manipulating JSON using the builtin [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library.

Comment: thanks - makes a lot of sense ! didn't think of it that way :)